# React-redux rerenders when creating arrays

Tags: reactjs, redux, render, connect, react-redux

I have a connected component where I would like to retrieve an array of objects. In my store, there is an array of ids, and an object where I keep the items like this:

```
const state = {
  items: [0, 1, 2],
  itemsById: {
    0: {},
    1: {},
    2: {},
  },
}
```

So using the `connect` function of react-redux, I do this in my component to inject the correct array:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  items: state.items.map((itemId) => state.itemsById[itemId]),
})
```

My app triggers updates **very often** (I dispatch actions in `requestAnimationFrame`), but the `items` array do not change during the process. By analyzing the app with the React Perf addon, it seems that my connected component makes unnecessary rendering, and I don't understand why because the `items` in the state don't change.

I already tried to make a memoized selector using reselect but it seems it does not change anything.

### Update (solution)

It works when you use a selector created with reselect. My problem was in the selector itself: my `items` array is located in a parent object which updates very frequently, and I was selecting this object instead of selecting the `items` array directly.

Don't do this:

```
const parentSelector = (state) => state.parent
const itemsByIdSelector = (state) => state.itemsById
const selector = createSelector(
  parentSelector,
  itemsByIdSelector,
  (parent, itemsById) => parent.items.map(...)
)
```

Do this:

```
const itemsSelector = (state) => state.items
const itemsByIdSelector = (state) => state.itemsById
const selector = createSelector(
  itemsSelector,
  itemsByIdSelector,
  (items, itemsById) => items.map(...)
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new array every time connect is called by doing this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  items: state.items.map((itemId) => state.itemsById[itemId]),
})
```

To prevent that use a [memoized selector](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html), which will return the same array every time, unless something actually changed. A selector is a method that computes the derived data from the state. [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) is a memoized selector library for redux.